# How to invoke Constructors by String in C# (i.e. by Reflection)?

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

I use the Chart class WPFToolKit and I want to invoke Construtors by String to short the code below

```
switch (node.Attributes["type"].Value)
{
    case "ColumnSeries":
        ans = new ColumnSeries();
        break;
    case "PieSeries":
        ans = new PieSeries();
        break;
    case "AreaSeries":
        ans = new AreaSeries();
        break;
    case "BarSeries":
        ans = new BarSeries();
        break;
    case "LineSeries":
        ans = new LineSeries();
        break;
}
```

After searching I find the code below:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(node.Attributes["type"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(type == null);
ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
object instance = ctor.Invoke(new object[]{});
```

But strangely, the type is always null and I don't why. Could anyone tell me that?
Thanks.

Comment: Try `Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(node.Attribute["type"].Value);`

Comment: it seems that the problem remains

Comment: If you cannot get a reference to the type, you can instantiate a object of the type.  Make sure you are using the correct Type name to get a reference to the Type.

Comment: I've tried "System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.ColumnSeries" but still no use. I think it's right reference.

Comment: It works now 'cause I need to add the assembly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your class has a public default constructor, you can use `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("your type"))`. But make sure you give it full type name (with namespace like "System.Int64").

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx

UPDATE:

If the type is in another assembly, refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233516/gettype-on-a-class-in-a-referenced-assembly-fails) to know how to get the type.

Comment: I tried object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.ColumnSeries")); but it's still "null"

Comment: See the update in my answer. Try to include its assembly name along with the full type name like Type.GetType("System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization‌​.Charting.ColumnSeries, WPFToolkit"); Replace "WPFToolkit" with whatever the name of the actual dll you have referenced

Answer (score 2):

`Type.GetType` expects a assembly-qualified name:

Here is the documentation about it:
"The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace."

This includes the namespace and the assembly of the type.
For example the assembly qualified name for the string class is something like this:

"System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

(I got that with `Console.WriteLine(typeof(string).AssemblyQualifiedName);`)